# PHP error uploading file to a folder error: failed to open stream: Permission denied (changing permissions on windows won't help either)

Tags: php

I'm currently having an issue trying to **upload a file (an image)** and sending it to a folder, this for a **CMS/blog** where people can **comment and create profiles with pictures**, unfortunately, **XAMPP** won't allow me to send it and it displays this message

```
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(../images/ ): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\CMS_TEMPLATE\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 19

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php37A6.tmp' to '../images/ ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\CMS_TEMPLATE\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 19
```

I know is a problem with the permission or privileges to read and change files, but even when I changed those permissions on the folder to let it write and modify files, the error messages still appear, I'm working on **windows 8.1 with XAMPP** and I haven't found a solution to this, it would be really helpful if anyone could help me. Also here's the code if anyone needs to see it.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['create_post'])) {
        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $post_author = $_POST['author'];
        $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category_id'];
        $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
        
        $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
        $post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
        
        $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
        $post_date = date('d-m-y');
        $post_comment_count = 4;
        move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/ " ); 
    }
?>
    
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="post_image">
</div>
```

***Thank you!***

Comment: better make sure the folder you are moving file to is writable by PHP (permission). Which permission has been set right now  ?

Comment: I've set it to give all permissions, but when i load xampp and attempt to upload the files, the error still appears, but exactly how would i go about giving permissions to php or the webserver so it can write to the folder? Because i'm not sure if i'm giving permissions to PHP per se, maybe i'm changing the permissions only for users

Comment: right click the mentioned folder and under "properties" > "General" fully uncheck attribute and you should be good."OK" then to finish.

Comment: You can also try to defining an absolute path to the upload folder and see if that works, incase the relative path points to the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `move_uploaded_file` is available in

**(PHP 4 >= 4.0.3, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)**

and in PHP's [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#86332) defined as following

**move_uploaded_file(string $from, string $to): bool**:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by from is a
> valid upload file ***(meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
> upload mechanism)***. If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
> filename given by to. This sort of check is especially important if
> there is any chance that anything done with uploaded files could
> reveal their contents to the user, or even to other users on the same
> system.
>
> This function *is **[open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)** aware*. However, restrictions are
> placed only on the to path as to allow the moving of uploaded files in
> which from may conflict with such restrictions. ***move_uploaded_file()
> ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files
> uploaded through PHP to be moved.***

**Return Values**

This functon **returns true on success**.

**1. If from is not a valid upload file**

Then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file(...) will return false.

**2. If from is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason**

Then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file(...) will return false. Additionally, a warning will be issued *(@MiguelDavid your case)*.

Referring to **[open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)** `string`

Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to access it. All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to avoid this restriction with a symlink. If the file doesn't exist then the symlink couldn't be resolved and the filename is compared to (a resolved) open_basedir.

open_basedir can affect more than just filesystem functions; for example if MySQL is configured to use mysqlnd drivers, LOAD DATA INFILE will be affected by open_basedir. Much of the extended functionality of PHP uses open_basedir in this way.
The special value . indicates that the working directory of the script will be used as the base-directory. This is, however, a little dangerous as the working directory of the script can easily be changed with chdir().

In **httpd.conf**, open_basedir can be turned off (e.g. for some virtual hosts) the same way as any other configuration directive with **"php_admin_value open_basedir none"**.

Under Windows, separate the directories with a semicolon. On all other systems, separate the directories with a colon. As an Apache module, open_basedir paths from parent directories are now automatically inherited.

The restriction specified with open_basedir is a directory name, not a prefix. The default is to allow all files to be opened.

open_basedir can be tightened at run-time. This means that if open_basedir is set to /www/ in php.ini a script can tighten the configuration to /www/tmp/ at run-time with ini_set(). When listing several directories, you can use the PATH_SEPARATOR constant as a separator regardless of the operating system.

---

Also take a look at [upload_tmp_dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) `string`

The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. **Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.**

If the directory specified here **is not writable**, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If **open_basedir** is on, then **the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.**

In your case xampp temporary directory is located:
**C:\xampp\tmp** and it,s also writable, so nothing to do there!

---

**... To fix your issue / finish ...**

Now that function ***move_uploaded_file is open_dir aware*** as already mentioned, give the directory for your images the appropriate owner permissions (e.g.: **0755**):

```
../images/
```

This will get you out of the issue!

Answer (score 0):

According to Dan Delaney on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#86332 you might need to set the "upload_tmp_dir" to an existing directory within you websites directory structure, since you are running on Windows.

Search for "upload_tmp_dir" in your php.ini file and set it to a path pointing to an existing directory:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "path_to_your_custom_tmp_dir"
```